# how can i resolver "ldd:fatal: could not load library libap.so.3" [QNX 6.5.0]

Tags: runtime-error, qnx

I am extremely new to `QNX`.

I created a photon Appbuilder project and when I run the application, it ends with below error

> ldd:fatal: could not load library libap.so.3

Comment: Improved readability

Answer (score 0):

Linker cannot find the lib. Just check that lib is present and stored in right place.